# Is there a way to have modules 'pre-installed' locally in node_modules?n

Tags: node.js, npm

### Automate Module Installation

I wish to not have to manually install dependencies that I use often for most of my projects, such as ESLint, Prettier, Nodemon, etc. I have been saving a long command to locally install all of these commonly used modules in each of my projects.

Is there a way that I can have all of them installed when I run `npm init` (I would prefer not to install everything globally)?

Thank You

Comment: define "pre-installed" and "automate installation".

Comment: i do it in vs-code remote containers in the entrypoint install all the global things, then devDependencies picks up the rest, btw you don't need any of them packages installed globally if they in devDependencies.. if your doing `npm init` then your initally starting fresh, else use git and clone a good base project with it all setup, remove the .git folder and do git init instead

Comment: could this be what you're after? https://yarnpkg.com/features/offline-cache/

Comment: @DevCl9 I was trying to avoid installing the same packages over and over again.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I did not think of that. I think that will work in my case. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is based on package.json, and package-lock.json. If you generate a project, you can save this off, and just copy it in.. Then run npm install, and you're done!

Edit: In my testing I've noticed you don't even need to run npm init, before npm install, but Mileage may vary.